# How can I add a shade3d object using specific coordinates to an rgl scene in R?

Tags: rgl

I have a 3d figure (in this case a hammerhead Shark) that has been loaded with:

shark3d= readOBJ("19412_Hammerhead_Shark_v2.OBJ")

This 3d object has been successfully added to an rgl scene using:

shade3d(shark3d, material = list(col = "darkgray"))

However, I would like to add this shade3d object to an specific coordinate inside the rgl scene.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please share how you tried to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `translate3d` and related functions to move `"mesh3d"` objects around in the scene.  For example,

```
shade3d(translate3d(shark3d, x = 10, y = 20, z = 30),
        material = list(col = "darkgray"))
```

or

```
shark3d %>% 
  translate3d(x = 10, y = 20, z = 30) %>% 
  shade3d(material = list(col = "darkgray"))
```

will move the (0,0,0) coordinate of the shape to (10,20,30).

Comment: Thank you very much!. It worked. 
I tried to use the shark as a "objid" inside the agecontrol function. However, when I open the widget as html, the shark does not appear in the scene.
Did you know if one can add this mesh object inside an agecontrol function?

Comment: No, but the result of calling `shade3d()` is a vector of objects (typically just one, but it depends on what's in your shark mesh).

Comment: Yes. When I call for the shade3d object, the result is : "rgllowlevel" "attr(*,"names")= chr"quads".